# How to retrieve raw file content from a repository commit with gitlab api?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-api

We can get list of repository commits by:

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/commits?path=:thefilename
```

We can get raw file content by blob id:

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/blobs/:sha/raw
```

However, the first api doesn't return blob id of each repository commit, and there is no known api that could retrieve raw file content using commit id instead. I need to retrieve the raw file content from a past repository commit instead of only the latest commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually not true. The API directly supports getting files from arbitrary references, as git directly supports:

> `GET /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path/raw`
>
> - `file_path` (required) - Url encoded full path to new file. Ex. lib%2Fclass%2Erb
> - `ref` (required) - The name of branch, tag **or commit**

Ex.:

> curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: ' 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb/raw?ref=master'

[Read More at Get raw file from repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-raw-file-from-repository)

Comment: I did not aware that the ref accepts commit id, thanks!